# Subversion 1.6.6 Error "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem"

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

I am running ubuntu server with Subversion 1.6.6.

In windows I use the latest Tortoise SVN compiled against Subversion 1.6.6.

I create a new Repository and when I attempt to view the repository or import my files and get the following error:

"Could not open the requested SVN filesystem"

I can view the repositories via the command line (as root) but want to view them in Tortoise.  Some repositories however are fine and I can view and comit without any problem via Tortoise.

I am sure its a user / permission thing but not sure where to look?

Any suggestions are greatly accepted.

Thank you

Comment: forgot to mention I did also install USVN which and had the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up perforoming a repository dump then re-installing ubuntu, subversion, then installed USVN (great app).  I next restored the repository from the dump.  Everything is working great now.

Answer (score 1):

How do you access the repository on your server? If you're using file:///, that won't work since the repository format isn't compatible  between OS. You have to use either svn:// or http(s):// to access the repository (and set up the corresponding server app).

If you're already using svn:// or http:// to access the repository, you can check the apache error log or run svnserve in console mode to get more detailed error messages.

your repositories must have full read/write access for the user who runs the server (svnserve or apache).